# How would I divide $\frac{4x^2-2x}{x^2+5x+4}\div \frac{2x}{x^2+2x+1}$?

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions

How would I divide $\frac{4x^2-2x}{x^2+5x+4}\div \frac{2x}{x^2+2x+1}$? Work would be appreciated. What would I do first?

Comment: Dividing by fractions is the same as multiplying by the reciprocal. Refer to your other post for how to multiply two fractions. In the future, please provide some work on your part. We are not a homework service.

Comment: Hint: factor. Note the definition of division of fractions.

Comment: @Cameron Williams my intention is not to ask "homework" questions, it is to ask questions about things I do not know how to do or am not sure how to do them.

Comment: If you are obtaining these problems from a textbook then the book should have some worked out examples and an explanation of the principles involved. Have you read the instructions and looked at the worked out examples?

Comment: Or look at the explanation in your previous question. If there is something you don't understand from that explanation ask for clarification about the process rather than just asking for the answer to what looks like a homework question.

Comment: I'm not getting these problems out of a textbook. I do not own one. And if I were to own a textbook, I would have provided instructions and a better explanation, however, I am not, and these problems are coming from my own curiosity. Also, just because someone asked multiple questions in a row, that does not mean that they are getting problems out from a textbook or a worksheet. If you are not here to help, please do not comment on my post/question.

Comment: My suggestion (which was not intended to contain sass) was to better your understanding of the general process rather then just look at isolated examples. A question such as "How does division of algebraic fractions work?" would be more suitable.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you can edit this, I would be able to answer. Thank you.

Comment: Ian Miller, unfortunately not everyone learns that way. There are many people like me who are visual learners and learn from examples rather than just looking at words. Yes, anyone who answers could give an example his/herself, but that may not happen and I would like to work with something rather than to read an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note first that 
$$
\frac{4x^2-2x}{x^2+5x+4}\div \frac{2x}{x^2+2x+1} = \frac{4x^2-2x}{x^2+5x+4} \times \frac{x^2+2x+1}{2x}.
$$
Now, we need to do some factorization, i.e.
$$
4x^2-2x=2x(2x-1)
$$
$$
x^2+5x+4=(x+1)(x+4)
$$
$$
x^2+2x+1=(x+1)(x+1)
$$
which gives rise to 
$$
\frac{4x^2-2x}{x^2+5x+4}\div \frac{2x}{x^2+2x+1} = \frac{2x(2x-1)}{(x+1)(x+4)} \times \frac{(x+1)(x+1)}{2x}
$$
and after cancellations, you would be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
Factorise the expression.
It's the same as 
$\frac{4x^2-2x}{2x} × \frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+5x+4}$

Comment: Okay.. So instead of cancelling terms from the numerator and denominator, can I cancel out terms from both the numerators if they have the same factor?

Comment: If you mean cancelling terms from $4x^2 - 2x$ and $x^2 + 2x + 1$ as the numerators, no. You cannot cancel common terms from the numerator.